# Complexheatmap with multiple files plotting

Tags: r, lapply, complexheatmap

I would like to use Complexheatmap for multiple files for plotting individual data frame or files .

So far I was able to do this as for small subset of files.

**Reading files as list**

```
list_of_files <- list.files('Model_hmap/',pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)


#Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
#all_csv <- lapply(list_of_files,read_delim,delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE,trim_ws = TRUE)

all_csv <- lapply(list_of_files,read.table,strip.white = FALSE,check.names = FALSE,header=TRUE,row.names=1)
#my_names = c("gene","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj","UP_DOWN")
my_names = c("Symbol","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj","UP_DOWN")

#my_names = c['X2']

#my_names = c("Peak","annotation","ENSEMBL","log2FoldChange","padj","UP_DOWN")
result_abd = lapply(all_csv, FUN = function(x) subset(x, select=-c(1:7,155)))





names(result_abd) <- gsub(".txt","",
                          list.files("Model_hmap/",full.names = FALSE),
                          fixed = TRUE)
```

Then **Scaling the data**

```
fun <- function(result_abd) {
  p <- t(scale(t(result_abd[,1:ncol(result_abd)])))
}

p2 <- mapply(fun, result_abd, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Next step was to use the metadata which i would like to annotate my heat-map

My metadata is as such

```
dput(head(metadata))
structure(list(patient = c("TCGA-AB-2856", "TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2971", 
"TCGA-AB-2930", "TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2872"), prior_malignancy = c("no", 
"no", "no", "no", "no", "no"), FAB = c("M4", "M0", "M4", "M2", 
"M1", "M3"), Risk_Cyto = c("Intermediate", "Poor", "Intermediate", 
"Intermediate", "Poor", "Good")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To read the above metadata I'm doing this below Im not sure if its the right way or approach.

```
list_of_files1 <- list.files('Model_hmap_meta/',pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)
#Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
meta1 <- lapply(list_of_files1,read.table, row.names = 1,sep = "\t",header = TRUE)
```

Now I'm stuck at the above step Im not sure how do I pass the argument as list which i have done for the dataframe of my gene expression which I had calculated the zscore which is a list. So I think the metadata should be the same class if I have to use this .

For single file This is how I used to annotation into my final plot

```
metadata =  read_delim("Model_hmap_meta/FAB_table.txt",delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE, 
                       trim_ws = TRUE)
head(metadata)
dim(metadata)
ann <- data.frame(metadata$FAB, metadata$Risk_Cyto)
colnames(ann) <- c('FAB', 'Risk_Cyto')
colours <- list('FAB' = c('M0' = 'red2', 'M1' = 'royalblue', 'M2'='gold','M3'='forestgreen','M4'='chocolate','M5'='Purple'),
                'Risk_Cyto' = c('Good' = 'limegreen', 'Intermediate' = 'navy' , 'N.D.' ='magenta','Poor'='black'))
colAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = ann,
                            which = 'col',
                            col = colours,
                            annotation_width = unit(c(1, 4), 'cm'),
                            gap = unit(1, 'mm'))
```

Now this is what I need to pass it to the list if I understand which I'm not able to do

My plotting function.

This is the code I use to plot.

```
hm1 <- Heatmap(heat,
               col= colorRamp2(c(-2.6,-1,0,1,2.6),c("blue","skyblue","white","lightcoral","red")),

                              #heatmap_legend_param=list(at=c(-2.6,-1,0,1,2.6),color_bar="continuous",
                #                         legend_direction="vertical", legend_width=unit(5,"cm"),
                 #                        title_position="topcenter", title_gp=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface="bold")),
               name = "Z-score",
               
               #Row annotation configurations
               cluster_rows=T,
               show_row_dend=FALSE,
               row_title_side="right",
               row_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=8),
               show_row_names=FALSE,
               row_names_side="left",
               
               #Column annotation configuratiions
               cluster_columns=T,
               show_column_dend=T,
               column_title="DE genes",
               column_title_side="top",
               column_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=15, fontface="bold"),
               show_column_names = FALSE,
               column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface="bold"),
               
               #Dendrogram configurations: columns
               clustering_distance_columns="euclidean",
               clustering_method_columns="complete",
               column_dend_height=unit(10,"mm"),
               
               #Dendrogram configurations: rows
               clustering_distance_rows="euclidean",
               clustering_method_rows="complete",
               row_dend_width=unit(4,"cm"),
               row_dend_side = "left",
               row_dend_reorder = TRUE,
               
               #Splits
               border=T,
               row_km = 1,
               column_km = 1,
               
               #plot params
               #width = unit(5, "inch"),
               #height = unit(4, "inch"),
               #height = unit(0.4, "cm")*nrow(mat),
               
               #Annotations
               top_annotation = colAnn)

# plot heatmap
draw(hm1, annotation_legend_side = "right", heatmap_legend_side="right")
```

**Objective**
How do I wrap all the above into a small function where I can take input multiple files and plot them.

**UPDATE**
Data files

My data [files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NJqOxEvF0lhQAJMTyFLE1YF5gJZdYakj?usp=sharing) my [metadafile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/166uvBILwD9qHwf_g3h8WdgxqQxZ_muir/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Could you clarify? You say that you want to know how to put that all into a function but have you tried that? What doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know how many files you're working with but usually when I have more than one matrix that I'm making a heatmap for I just pass the individual file to the function and the function is where I set up the annotation bars and such according to the file I pass in

Comment: ' You say that you want to know how to put that all into a function but have you tried that?' yes that i tried it doesnt work ."I just pass the individual file to the function and the function is where I set up the annotation bars and such according to the file I pass in" this is what I need since My annotation is constant one common file..

Comment: @mfeldbauer I was able to do the scaling of the data frame next what I was not sure how to pass the annotation the last dataframe since I am not sure if the annotation will pass a as list to the final function or or other ways ``

Comment: Have you made a heatmap before with complex heatmap? I ask because I don't see any of your annotation bars or anything here like `rowAnnotation` or `HeatmapAnnotation`. Setting those up is the majority of my function

Comment: Do you need to use a list? You said that the annotation file is the same for every matrix

Comment: The part that you need to set up is the annotation bar calls. Once you have those all worked out you can just put them in the function and then outside of the function just read in your files and pass the expression matrix and metadata file to the function

Comment: "Have you made a heatmap before with complex heatmap" yes for single files or individual data frame not with list of files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code you provided I made the following function (`make_heatmap`). Some of the read in statements are altered to match what I was working with on my machine. I also only used 2 of your files but it should work with all 4 that you're using.

This function will allow you to pass the counts matrix (which you normalize and set up **before** passing to the function). The assumption is that you're using the same metadata/annotation for each file you're passing. If you have different annotation files you could set up the heatmap annotation before the function and then pass that to the function. This is a bit more tedious though.

Usually the way that I set up my heatmap analyzes is that I have a script containing all of my functions (one for each type of heatmap I have to make) and then every time I need to make a new heatmap I have another script where I read in/prepare (ie median center) my counts matrix and then call the heatmap function I need.

```
list_of_files <- dir(pattern = 'MAP', full.names = TRUE)

#Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
#all_csv <- lapply(list_of_files,read_delim,delim = "\t", escape_double = FALSE,trim_ws = TRUE)

all_csv <- lapply(list_of_files,read.table,strip.white = FALSE,check.names = FALSE,header=TRUE,row.names=1)
#my_names = c("gene","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj","UP_DOWN")
my_names = c("Symbol","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj","UP_DOWN")

#my_names = c['X2']

#my_names = c("Peak","annotation","ENSEMBL","log2FoldChange","padj","UP_DOWN")
result_abd = lapply(all_csv, FUN = function(x) subset(x, select=-c(1:7,155)))

names(result_abd) <- gsub(".txt","",
                          list.files("Model_hmap/",full.names = FALSE),
                          fixed = TRUE)

fun <- function(result_abd) {
  p <- t(scale(t(result_abd[,1:ncol(result_abd)])))
}

p2 <- mapply(fun, result_abd, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# list_of_files1 <- list.files('Model_hmap_meta/',pattern = '\\.txt$', full.names = TRUE)
# #Further arguments to read.csv can be passed in ...
# meta1 <- lapply(list_of_files1,read.table, row.names = 1,sep = "\t",header = TRUE)


make_heatmap<-function(counts_matrix){
  
  metadata =  read.table("FAB_table.txt",sep = "\t", header=1)
  
  head(metadata)
  dim(metadata)
  ann <- data.frame(metadata$FAB, metadata$Risk_Cyto)
  colnames(ann) <- c('FAB', 'Risk_Cyto')
  colours <- list('FAB' = c('M0' = 'red2', 'M1' = 'royalblue', 'M2'='gold','M3'='forestgreen','M4'='chocolate','M5'='Purple'),
                  'Risk_Cyto' = c('Good' = 'limegreen', 'Intermediate' = 'navy' , 'N.D.' ='magenta','Poor'='black'))
  colAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = ann,
                              which = 'col',
                              col = colours,
                              annotation_width = unit(c(1, 4), 'cm'),
                              gap = unit(1, 'mm'))
  
  hm1 <- Heatmap(counts_matrix,
                 col= colorRamp2(c(-2.6,-1,0,1,2.6),c("blue","skyblue","white","lightcoral","red")),
                 
                 #heatmap_legend_param=list(at=c(-2.6,-1,0,1,2.6),color_bar="continuous",
                 #                         legend_direction="vertical", legend_width=unit(5,"cm"),
                 #                        title_position="topcenter", title_gp=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface="bold")),
                 name = "Z-score",
                 
                 #Row annotation configurations
                 cluster_rows=T,
                 show_row_dend=FALSE,
                 row_title_side="right",
                 row_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=8),
                 show_row_names=FALSE,
                 row_names_side="left",
                 
                 #Column annotation configuratiions
                 cluster_columns=T,
                 show_column_dend=T,
                 column_title="DE genes",
                 column_title_side="top",
                 column_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=15, fontface="bold"),
                 show_column_names = FALSE,
                 column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 12, fontface="bold"),
                 
                 #Dendrogram configurations: columns
                 clustering_distance_columns="euclidean",
                 clustering_method_columns="complete",
                 column_dend_height=unit(10,"mm"),
                 
                 #Dendrogram configurations: rows
                 clustering_distance_rows="euclidean",
                 clustering_method_rows="complete",
                 row_dend_width=unit(4,"cm"),
                 row_dend_side = "left",
                 row_dend_reorder = TRUE,
                 
                 #Splits
                 border=T,
                 row_km = 1,
                 column_km = 1,
                 
                 #plot params
                 #width = unit(5, "inch"),
                 #height = unit(4, "inch"),
                 #height = unit(0.4, "cm")*nrow(mat),
                 
                 #Annotations
                 top_annotation = colAnn)
  
  # plot heatmap
  draw(hm1, annotation_legend_side = "right", heatmap_legend_side="right")
}

make_heatmap(as.matrix(p2[[1]])) #just call the function with the counts matrix
make_heatmap(as.matrix(p2[[2]]))
```

If you need to output the heatmap to a pdf or something, you can do that before calling the function or you can put that command inside of the heatmap function (just make sure to call `dev.off()` inside the function too in that case).

Comment: thank you another way to do it..although i managed to put it inside a function although a clumsy one